# The current theme cannot be loaded when I start my machine

Tags: boot, 20.04

When I start my laptop it shows me:

```
The current theme cannot be loaded due to the errors below, please select another theme.

file///usr/share/sddm/breeze/main.qml: No such file or directory
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: I would likely `dpkg -S usr/share/sddm/breeze/main.qml`  (ie. ask your system which package it came from); which should show a package where a replacement file can be located. Alternatively just switch to a different `sddm` theme; as Kubuntu/KDE makes that very easy (you're bound to find one you love - there are thousands!)

Answer (score 1):

You have to reinstall the [package which provides missed */usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze/Main.qml* file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=breeze%2Fmain.qml).

Go to tty3 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, login to it and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall sddm-theme-breeze
```

then reboot.

Comment: I run both above command but nothing happen and issue remain as it is

Comment: Then you have to carefully run filesystem check and then `debsums -a -s` on this broken system.